# What's the difference between "Artificial neuron" and "Perceptron"?

Tags: neural-networks

The basic building block of a neural network are artificial neurons as you can see in the picture below the circles represent the artificial neurons.[image]

What's a Perceptron? How it is different from the artificial neuron?

Answer (score 6):

[Perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is an early type of a neural network for binary classification without hidden layers. It is a model of the form
$$
y=\sigma(\mathbf w^T \mathbf x)
$$
where $\sigma$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). It can be trained using the perceptron algorithm.

You could say that perceptron is a neural network with a single neuron.

[image: Schematic of the perceptron model]

Image from https://towardsdatascience.com/what-the-hell-is-perceptron-626217814f53

Comment: That makes sense. Can we have more than one neurons?